# Friend of the class is inaccesible

Tags: c++, oop, friend-class

i am trying to write a very simple code as a practice. The problem is when i make friend a member function of one class to another, it says inaccesible but when i declare the whole class as friend of another class it works fine.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class gpa2;
class gpa1 {
private:
    int no1;
    int no2;
public:
    void setnum1(int n1, gpa2&xp) {
        cout << " the friend member function is : " << xp.no4;
    }
    void setnum2(int n2) {
        no2 = n2;
        cout << "num2 is : " << no2 << endl;
    };
};

class gpa2 {
private:
    int no3;
    int no4;
    friend void gpa1::setnum1(int, gpa2&);
public:
    void setnum3(int n3) {
        no3 = n3;
        cout << "num3 is : " << no3 << endl;
    }
    void getnum4(int n4) {
        cout << "num4 is :  " << n4 << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    gpa1 g1;
    gpa2 g2;
    g1.setnum1(15, g2);
    g1.setnum2(30);
    g2.setnum3(45);
    g2.getnum4(50);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you add what do you expect from that code as output, it'd be better to understand the logic you want to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xp.no4` is not accessible, as `setnum1` is a member function of `gpa1`, not `gpa2`

Implementing the function `setnum1(int, gpa2&)` is not necessary when defining it, and causing problems here: At the time of defining `class gpa1` `setnum1` can't be implemented, as `class gpa2` is not yet defined. BUT implementing it after defining `gpa2` is no problem at all.

Therefore, with some small changes: [Godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/CcvjUr)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// forward declaration
class gpa2;

class gpa1 {
private:
    int no1;
    int no2;
public:
    void setnum1(int n1, gpa2& xp);
    void setnum2(int n2) {
        no2 = n2;
        cout << "num2 is : " << no2 << endl;
    };
};

class gpa2 {
private:
    int no3;
    int no4;
    friend void setnum1(int, gpa2&);
public:
    void setnum3(int n3) {
        no3 = n3;
        cout << "num3 is : " << no3 << endl;
    }
    void getnum4(int n4) {
        cout << "num4 is :  " << n4 << endl;
    }

    int num4() { return no4; } // added accesibility to no4
};

// implementation of setnum1
void gpa1::setnum1(int n1, gpa2& xp)  {
    cout << " the friend member function is : " << xp.num4();
}



int main() {
    gpa1 g1;
    gpa2 g2;
    g1.setnum1(15, g2);
    g1.setnum2(30);
    g2.setnum3(45);
    g2.getnum4(50);
    return 0;
}
```